# Can we add more keyboards for Extra Keys?

Tags: keyboard

I think the question is quite clear. :) Is there any way possible that we can use more than 1 keyboard, and program them with programs like autohotkey for the purpose of 'Extra Keys' ? Thank you very much.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIFE7h3m40U is worth a watch. Not really dived into luamacros much, but that seems to be roughly what you're talking about

Comment: Starting to watch the video. Thank you first :) and have a good day @JourneymanGeek